# OneNote app -> Save images from Notebook to local storage

Tags: images, microsoft-onenote

is there any way in the Android App to save an image from a notebook to local sdcard except for taking a screenshot which in fact gives me a quality loss, especially on detailed high-res pictures?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On my OnePlus 6 running latest OneNote from Play Store, when I long-press an image, Gallery is listed as an option. From Gallery you can really do virtually anything, specifically, "sharing" to another app. Then you can find a way to save the image.

Comment: Very strange, when I longpress an image, a circle with a arrow-cross appears and the image is selected, but it only says: *copy, cut, paste, select everything, alternative text*. Any ideas? EDIT: I've put the image into the notebook from the browser on my computer. Now I just tried to put an image from my smartphone into a notebook - and yes indeed, I can open it afterwards in my gallerie. VERY STRANGE!